# Opening a simple function in a file stream c++

Tags: c++, file, stream

If I have a simple function that prints to standard output maybe something like an integer or lets say a string like "Flipy flops", then is there a way to call the same function but instead of printing to standard output it prints the string "Flipy flops" to a file stream? (provided of course I've opened the file and all that stuff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes just give it an `ostream&` parameter

```
void my_function(...)
{
    cout << ...
}
```

becomes

```
void my_function(ostream& out, ...)
{
    out << ...
}
```

Comment: wait so if i call it with that extra parameter cout << becomes out << ?

Comment: "`cout <<` becomes `out <<`?" yes, but only in that scope.

Comment: @BrianCain `out` is just a variable name, it doesn't become `cout`. It's being used in a similar way to how `cout` is normally used, that's all. And if you used `cout` in `my_function` it would still be the same.

Comment: @john, I understand this.  I was expanding on your "yes (or use whatever name you prefer)" to make sure that user2710184 didn't think this was some global lexical substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Using [fstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) works just like cin and cout.

```
void SomeMethod( )
{
    ofstream myFile( "myFile.txt" );
    myFile << FlipyFlops( );
    myFile.close( );
}

char* FlipyFlops( )
{
    return "flipy flops"; // or "flippy floppies", whichever you prefer
}
```

[ofstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) is for output to a file and [ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) is for reading from a file.

Comment: Ahem, point of order.  The desire was to write "Flipy flops" -- what is this "flippy floppies" business?  Clearly not answering the question.  -1.   ;)

Comment: Edited to be more on point, while retaining original comedic value.